# trying to save regex in mongo db '\' character gets removed every time

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to save list of regex in mongodb.

But while saving the values `'\'` char present in value automatically gets removed. 
e.g; `"val":/55\sA\.?B\.?C\.?\s/`

after insertion it becomes
`"val":/5sA.?B.?C.?s/`

Comment: You need to escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your characters with `\`. For example, if you're trying to add the **?** character, you need to do something like `...\?B.\?c...`.
I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: thanks for replying but the problem remains... i want to add escape character \ in regex.eg. /ab\./  this exact regex as it is i want to save in mongo.
But after saving the value becomes /ab./

Comment: Can you edit your post and put your insertion query?

Comment: I was trying to insert with GUI that was messing things up.When i did from command line it worked.But I noticed to add \ as character extra\ is to be added as escape character if being done from GUI.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting/upvoting it. Thanks